# Rails - How to send parameters from form to def create in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this create function

```
    def create
  @project = current_user.projects.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_create(project_params)
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:success] = "Project not created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

What im trying to do is get data to the params:id so i can check if the object already exists.

Heres the relevant form

```
  <%= bootstrap_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :project_title, :value=>params[:project_title] , label: "Title"%>
    </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">


      <div class="field project-save-button">
        <%= f.submit "Save Entry",   class: "btn-sm btn-danger" %>
      </div> <% end %>
```

When i hit the submit button the SQL query generated is

```
SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = ? AND "projects"."project_title" IS NULL  ORDER BY "projects"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
```

How do i properly send through a parameter from form to controller?

**projects_controller**

```
 class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    if current_user.projects.create(project_params)
      flash[:success] = "Project created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:success] = "Project not created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Project deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  def update
    @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
    if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
      flash[:success] = "Project updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:success] = "Project not updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

    private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:project_title, :project_subject, :project_type, :project_worth, :project_due_date, :project_details)
  end

  def correct_user
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @project.nil?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a hidden field to the form with the projects id:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :id, @project.id %>
```

**Update**

I think the main problem is caused by you trying to use the create action for either creating a project or updating a project. You should really only be creating a new project in the create action and use an update action to update an existing project.

You could do something like the below to make your create action work for both but it's a bit hacky:

In your view

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:id, @project.id) if @project.persisted? %>
```

In your controller

```
if params[:id]
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  @project.assign_attributes(project_params)
else
  @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
end
if @project.save
...
```

**The right way**

I haven't used `bootstrap_form_for` but it should work that same as the normal `form_for` except for the field formatting.

When you do:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
```

It should automatically check if @project is persisted or not and make the form a `new` form if it isn't or make it a `edit` form if it is.

The new form will submit to the `create` action and the `edit` form should automatically insert the projects id in a `hidden_field` and will submit to the `update` action. Therefore you should be able to keep your original view code but add an update action in your controller like so:

Update action

```
def update
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
    flash[:success] = "Project updated!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:success] = "Project not updated!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Create action

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:success] = "Project not created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

You'll need to make sure you have the update route in your routes too. Probably just:

```
# routes.rb
resources :projects
```

**Adding an edit form**

Somewhere in your views you need to create an edit form. This is if you want to make a edit form for all of current_users's projects:

```
<% current_user.projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= bootstrap_form_for(project) do |f| %>
  ... # rest of form here etc
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How do i actually send though the parameter after that?

Comment: When you click the submit button on a form it gets all the fields associated with that form and send them to the controller in a `params` hash. So if you put that hidden field in your form and click submit, the params hash in your create action should contain a `params[:id]` with the projects id. You can check what params are being sent to the controller if you look at your server console. Let me know if that's not clear : )

Comment: Its giving undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass. Is there something i have to change?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. It could be that your html doesn't seem to be structured correctly, e.g there are no closing `</div>`s for your columns. The form's opening and closing tags should be on the same level, i.e you can't have a form opening outside a column then have it closing ( the `<% end %>` ) inside a column

Comment: Actually I think it might be that if the project is not persisted then it's id will be nil so the hidden_field doesn't work, I'll update my answer hopefully to fix it

Comment: the second parameter is causing the error @project.id. when i cut that out the page loads fine.

Comment: Im getting an undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass when i add that to the create controller.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It just always goes to the create and makes a new project. I also notice theres no id parameter in the SQL now.

Comment: The route was in there all along. What is the usual way of updating an entry and how come this has become a problem? Is it because im using the same form to create and update?

Comment: The sql you're seeing is only the code inside the action querying the database. Your original query `SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = ? AND "projects"."project_title" IS NULL  ORDER BY "projects"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]` is caused by this line `@project = current_user.projects.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_create(project_params)`. I'm not sure what the problem is. It seems to be that your form_for is generating a `new project` form even for already existing projects.

Comment: Normally you would have a `new` action which would set up a view where there is a new project form which would point to the `create` action. You would have a separate `edit` action which would set up a view for the edit project form and would point to the `update` action. Often though they are combined into one form which checks if it is a new project or a pre existing project. As Zhilang was asking, where is your @project coming from?

Comment: I assume the problem lies in that the page is a static page home which has %= render 'shared/project_form' %> which points to shared/_project_form.html.erb

Comment: Maybe ive made a mistake but it seems to display a form for every single project i.e about 30 stacked on top of each other. Is that the .each causing it?

Comment: Yes. I have no idea what your end goal is but at least now you should have a working new project form and working edit project forms. If you want a different page for every form you should make a link for each project to an edit page. and that would need an projects edit action. I'd recommend checking out [The rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) to learn the basics. This question has been answered in my opinion. You could open another if you need more help

Comment: Great. After all that i made a show.html.erb and it worked from there. had to basically copy and paste the homepage over to the show page.

Comment: Nice! Glad you've got it sorted out : )

Comment: Highly appreciate it. If you want an idea of what we where dealing with its here https://radiant-sea-5676.herokuapp.com/ username a@a.com pass foobar

Answer (score 0):

you only provide the create method, can you also provide the controller method that render the html form? I mean what is the 
`@project` in `<%= bootstrap_form_for(@project) do |f| %>`
I think it should be your new method in the same controller

Comment: theres no new method in the controller.

Comment: Where does your @project come from?

Comment: Im not sure. How can i check that?

Comment: can you just copy the whole controller here? and also can you copy paste your console log after you load this page on your browser?

Comment: projects_controller was added and do you mean the form page?

Comment: Logs after i submit the form when it should be updating but inserts new http://pastebin.com/GtYwssdZ

Comment: I believe the problem is your `@project` instance. Somewhere in either your static_pages#home action or in your views you must be assigning something to @project. So far we have no idea what that is. Either you will be doing something like `@project = current_user.projects.new` to instantiate a new project or for a pre existing project you must be doing `@project = current_user.projects.first` or something similar. COuls you show us where this is happening? For both the case when a new project is instantiated and also for when @project is assigned to a pre existing project?

Comment: I think @Subtletree is right, can you attach your StaticPagesController here, and also your route.rb? that helps to analyze the whole process

Comment: in rails form_for helper will automatically generate html for you depends on whether the model you send is a new instance or already exist in database. If it's a new instance, following the convention, it will send `POST /projects`, and if it is an exist object with id, then it will send `PUT /projects/:id`

Comment: Any way of forcing it to go to PUT?

Comment: Cool so it looks like your problem is that your `@project` is always a new project. Never a pre existing project. To edit an existing project you need to have some differnet code, ill add to my answer

Comment: now we see your static controller, I can see in your `home` method, you defined `@project = current_user.projects.build if logged_in?`. it means every time `@project` will be a new instance of Project without id, because it's not saved yet therefore not persist in database.

Comment: the proper way of forcing it to go to PUT in this case is u need to give fetch an existing project from database, otherwise rails does not have an clue about which project you want to update

Comment: for example, `@project = Project.find(id: 1)`

Comment: the flow of how it works is this:
1. browser does `GET "/"`
2. rails router goes to `routes.rb` to find your routing rules, in your case, I think it goes to `static_pages#home`, which means the StaticPagesController's home method will prepare the response for browser
3. in your controller you wrote
   `@project = current_user.projects.build if logged_in?`
   `@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]).reorder("project_due_date ASC")`

Comment: so the controller will assign a new Project instance to `@project` with `user_id` set to the `current_user.id`, then assign your current_user's feed to `@feed_items`
4. following convention, rails will render a template which is views/static_pages/home.html.erb
5. inside this template, you renders the _form.html.erb template which is not going to affect anything
6. then all rails does is just putting in the `@project` and `@feed_items` in your template file, and then send the html response back to your browser

Comment: so in this case, you need to explain your purpose more clearly. How many projects can a user create? If they can create multiple ones, why do you want to check whether the project already exist or not by id?